# Link an image in the home page with a carousel of a gallery page

Tags: javascript, html, carousel

I am a beginner looking for some help.
I try to build a specific carousel.

My index.html page displays only the first three images of a gallery.

I would like that when we click on one specific image in the index.html page, this very image displays in the gallery.html page, and we can view other images with a carousel using the right/left arrow of the keyboard.

Th carousel seems to work fine...but there is one major problem: Whatever image we click on the index.html page, it is the first one that shows up in the gallery.

This is the index.html code:

```
    <div id="extrait">
        <a href="gallery.html"><img src="assets/image1.jpg" alt="Image 1" onclick="updateIndex(1)"></a>
        <a href="gallery.html"><img src="assets/image2.jpg" alt="Image 2" onclick="updateIndex(2)"></a>
        <a href="gallery.html"><img src="assets/image3.jpg" alt="Image 3" onclick="updateIndex(3)"></a>

    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Then, this is the gallery.html code:

```
<body>
    <h1>Gallery</h1>
    <div id="carousel">
        <img src="assets/image1.jpg" alt="Image 1">
        <img src="assets/image2.jpg" alt="Image 2">
        <img src="assets/image3.jpg" alt="Image 3">
        <img src="assets/image4.jpg" alt="Image 4">
        <img src="assets/image5.jpg" alt="Image 5">
        <img src="assets/image6.jpg" alt="Image 6">
        <img src="assets/image7.jpg" alt="Image 7">
        <img src="assets/image8.jpg" alt="Image 8">
        <img src="assets/image9.jpg" alt="Image 9">
      
    </div>
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

At last, this is the javascript part (script.js part):

```
const galleryImages = document.querySelectorAll('#carousel img');
let currentIndex = 0;

function showImage(index) {
   
    galleryImages.forEach((image, i) => {
        if (i === index) {
            image.style.display = 'block'; console.log("Index :", index);
        } else {
            image.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
}


showImage(currentIndex);


//Gallery Carousel
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    if (event.key === 'ArrowLeft') {
       
        currentIndex = (currentIndex - 1 + galleryImages.length) % galleryImages.length;
        showImage(currentIndex);
    } else if (event.key === 'ArrowRight') {
      
        currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % galleryImages.length;
        showImage(currentIndex);
    }
});


// updateIndex

function updateIndex(index) {
    currentIndex = index;

    showImage(currentIndex);
}
```

How can I ensure that I always end up at the correct image in gallery.html?

Comment: When you click from the main page into the gallery, you get a whole new page. A whole new page means that the code in your script is run from the beginning again; it's a completely new environment. Thus setting the index on the main page will have no effect, because in the gallery page the index will be reset to 0. You'll have to pass the desired index through as a HTTP parameter so that the gallery page can initialize the index appropriately.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am very grateful! But how to do that?

Comment: You can add a parameter to the URLs in the main page, like `?index=2` or whatever, and then in the gallery page you can examine the URL to initialize the index. [See this MDN page for details.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/get#examples)

Answer (score 1):

You should see html pages as completely isolated programs. Every time you click a link, or reload a page, the following thing happens:

- the current page is removed
- all the javascript code in the current page stops running
- all the variables your code created, stop existing

then

- the new html page is downloaded, and rendered
- all the javascript files in the new html page are executed, from scratch.
- the code doesn't know anything about what was in the previous page, it doesn't even know what is in other browser tabs.

Your issue comes from the fact that you have two separate html pages. Even though you included the same javascript file in both of them, this does not mean that there is shared data between them. The global variable in the second page will not contain the value set in the first page.

The correct solution for your case should be to pass the data about the image you want to open in the url:

in index.html, modify the urls to be like this:

```html
 <div id="extrait">
        <a href="gallery.html#1"><img src="assets/image1.jpg" alt="Image 1" onclick="updateIndex(1)"></a>
        <a href="gallery.html#2"><img src="assets/image2.jpg" alt="Image 2" onclick="updateIndex(2)"></a>
        <a href="gallery.html#3"><img src="assets/image3.jpg" alt="Image 3" onclick="updateIndex(3)"></a>

    </div>
```

in the javascript code, you can add some code that as soon as the page loads:

- checks the url, and retieves the hash, which is the part of the url after the # symbol.
- set the current index based on that hash

```js
const galleryImages = document.querySelectorAll('#carousel img');
let currentIndex = 0;
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      // Get the hash from the URL
      var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
      // Show the image corresponding to the hash
      if (hash) {
        currentIndex = Number(hash);
        showImage(currentIndex);
      }
    });

    // the rest of your code ...
```

Note that this script is required only in the gallery.html page

Comment: This is a well explained answer! I would just suggest that instead of using hashes (which are primarily for denoting an anchor location on the destination page), you use query strings, which are more appropriate for passing data between pages.

Comment: Additionally (and this is just me nitpicking), you can eliminate the DOMContentLoaded event handler and just place the script just prior to the closing `body` tag. Or better yet, since we're talking about displaying images, set up a `load` event handler for the code.